# Django - Liste index in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a problem with my template.

I know how to use list.index to get a value from a list, but now my index value is `list.container.id (=1)`.

So, I have stupidly try `list.container.id` and is not working like `list.1`.

Comment: Can you provide code of what you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As pointed out the old answer was wrong,

New Solution:

Create a custom filter tag.

In your app, create a python module called templatetags (create a folder and place an **init**.py file in it) then create a py file for your custom filter, for ex: my_custom_filter.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def index_my_list(my_list, index):
    try:
        return my_list[index]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Use in your template as

```
{{list|index_my_list:container.id}}
```

All this being said, it is best to keep your logical code in the view, you might want to reconsider your data structures

---

Wrong Solution:

Assign container.id to a variable then use it

```
{% with container.id as foo %}

{{list.foo}}
```

Comment: Not a solution .. `foo` will be treated as an attribute of list. `{{list[foo]}}` might work, but entirely sure.

Comment: @Pjot edited with a different solution. Als FYI django template doesn't support square bracket indexing, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

Comment: Just realised that you get a list index out of range error if incorrectly indexed, added exception handling code for it